# php how to post date range picker with 2 variables

Tags: php, daterangepicker

I'm using date range picker

```
<input class="form-control input-daterange-datepicker" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 31/01/2015" />
```

When I post the form i get 1 value for this range. 
is it possible to get 2 values - from and till (when i post)?

```
<!-- Date range Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendors/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script>
// Daterange picker
$('.input-daterange-datepicker').daterangepicker({
    buttonClasses: ['btn', 'btn-sm'],
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    minDate: '06/01/2015',
    maxDate: '06/30/2025',      
    applyClass: 'btn-danger',
    cancelClass: 'btn-inverse',
    dateLimit: {
        days: 45
    }       
});
</script>
```

I think that this is the right project -

https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker

Comment: I imagine its posted to php as one value and needs splitting. Can you post the result of var_dump($_POST['daterange']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget will post both the dates as one string. Since you named your input `daterange` you can access the result in `PHP` using:

```
$aRanges = explode(' - ', $_POST['daterange']);
var_dump($aRanges);
```